# GeoIP to automatically change currency based on user location WordPress

Tags: wordpress, geolocation, geoip

I am building a website with wordpress that sells coffee(example), i need to grab the users location and from obtaining that location, automatically updatethe currency on the site to match their currency.

Is there any support or plugin that does exactly this?

NB! from my searches i've found a few but you need to set them, i want it to be done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in this (commercial) API : https://db-ip.com/api/jsdoc.php#currencies

It does automatic conversion of prices based on the detected visitor location and doesn't require additional plugins on the WordPress side.